# SBC Environment Setup

Tags: ros2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I got an trouble when I followed the instruction below.

[link text](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/#sbc-setup)

16.2.7.1 Domain ID Allocation

I made a mistake when typing commands.

I wrote  `echo 'source ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/setp.bash' >> ~/.bashrc` by mistake. (setup>>setp)

I wrote correct commands and rebooted, but

`home/ubuntu/turtlebot3_ws/install/setp.bash: No such file or directory`  appears.

Do you know how to delete the history that  I wrote the incorrect commands ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344410/sbc-environment-setup/) by [shunta ito](https://answers.ros.org/users/51343/shunta-ito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What the `echo 'source ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/setp.bash' >> ~/.bashrc` command does is writing `source ~/turtlebot3_ws/install/setp.bash` at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file.

To correct it you need to edit (with a text editor, e.g. nano) the `~/.bashrc` file and modify the line from `setp.bash` to `setup.bash`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shunta ito](https://answers.ros.org/users/51343/shunta-ito/) on 2020-02-18**:
Thank you!
The problem was solved.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-18**:
As this solved the issue, can you please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left so that this doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions